# Any Component or Module Available for Product Comparision in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I need a joomla component or module for product comparision...pls advise me...

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to do this with a shopping cart component, use:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-related-products/8010

If you're not wanting to use a shopping cart and are wanting to do it more free-form, try:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews/11305

Hope this helps!